# Number of legal paths on a grid?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math

In the grid below, a step is legal if it begins in any hexagon and moves to an adjacent hexagon that contains a different letter. Assuming you can start anywhere, compute the total number of distinct, directed paths of 2 legal steps.
[image]

I'm not sure of any way to do this without simply bashing it out and counting all the paths. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by a path.  Is $A\to O$ a path or do you mean something like $A_1\to O_1$ (numbering the hexagons from left to right)?

Comment: Assuming you mean the latter:  assign two integers $(a,b)$ to each hexagon:  $a$, the number of one step paths that end there and $b$ the number of one step paths that start there.  Then $a\times b$ is the number of two-step paths with the given hexagon as the middle.  I'm not entirely sure of the rules, but I think it is possible that $a=b$, and that both are simply the number of differently lettered neighbors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First tabulate the amount of of $1$-step paths from each node (write it in the node):

[image: length 1 paths]

Then for the $2$-step paths from a node $x$ add up the amounts of $1$ step paths of each neighboring node (to where you can move from $x$), for example:

[image: example calculation of length 2 path amounts]

Explanation: You can count all the $2$-step paths by considering the first step of the path. It can be to any neighboring tile and then you can continue from that tile with any $1$-step path.

Calculating this for all nodes we get:

[image: length 2 paths]

Now we add all these up to get the total number of $2$ step paths, which is $110$.

**Note:** this is equivalent to calculating the powers of the adjacency matrix of the graph connected to this problem (the nodes are the tiles and there is an directed edge between nodes when you can move from one to the other). You can continue in the same manner for longer paths ($3$ steps and so on) by doing the similar summation for the previously gotten values.